# How to write this regex in ColdFusion?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Could someone please help me solve the issue I meet trying to write this regex in ColdFusion ?
I'd like to have a function which would return :

- 1 if a string looks exactly like item_name-Copy(xxx) where item_name is a variable and xxx can be any integer
- 0 if not

I tried with rematch but still haven't found what I'm looking for

What I get in the dump is an empty array while I expected to get 1
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to escape `(` and `)` as `\(` and `\)`. They're regex [metacharacters used for a group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
2. `[:digit:]` should be `[[:digit:]]`. It's a [POSIX character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).
3. `[[:digit:]]` should be repeated once or more as `[[:digit:]]+`
4. You may as well use `\d+` to match digits.
5. Use [`REFind()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e9a.html) instead of [`REMatch()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e35.html) to get `0` or `1` as result.

**Regex:**

```
^\w+-Copy\(\d+\)$
```

**Code:**

```
<cfset nameItem = "item_name-Copy(1)"> 
<cfset result = REFind("^\w+-Copy\(\d+\)$",nameItem)> 
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mariano, you made my day !

Comment: Why're you using `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d`?

Comment: Good question. The OP was using it in a comment he deleted. I used it to stress what was wrong with his code. I'll edit for future reference.